# Spring-WS does not marshall the request object. Empty request is sent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws

I am calling a SOAP webservice in a Spring Boot project using Spring WebserviceTemplate. My client class extends WebServiceGatewaySupport. I cannot post the actual code, but this is a sample.

```
Response response = (Response) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request, new SoapActionCallback("http://tempuri.org/rpc/Gateway/"));
```

When this request is sent, I am getting response code 400. I enabled trace logging for Spring and found that an empty request is sent.

> TRACE o.s.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent.sendRequest - Sent request []

When I tried to create a simpler web service client using the same components - Spring Boot project using Spring WebserviceTemplate, I can see that it sends a valid XML payload and it works.

I have now found that this error happens only as part of a larger existing project - the request object being marshaled as an empty string. It is just sending an empty payload. There are no errors in the log before the call is made to webservice.

The request and response POJO are generated by maven-jaxb2-plugin & I have verified that the package and schema are correct.

I have verified that the Marshaller (Jaxb2Marshaller) and its context path are set correctly, and it marshals the request object when called separately.

How can I debug this? Please give your suggestions.

Comment: Hello Shankar, were you able to resolve the issue? I am facing something similar.

Comment: @NaveenAttri I cant remember how I proceeded with this issue. I suggest starting a new question with more details, since this question was just a prototype and it was based on an older version of Spring.